# Flask, CherryPy and static content

Tags: deployment, flask, cherrypy, wsgiserver

I know there are plenty of questions about [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) and static files but I still can't seem to get this working.

There's a snippet to deploy a Flask app on CherryPy here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/

Is there a quick modification to have the wsgiserver serve the content in the static directory of the flask app?

The static content features of CherryPy seem to reside within CherryPy.  And I am unsure on how to mount a CherryPy app that does nothing but serve static content while working with this snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a snippet that should do what you are asking for. This is based on the [set of instructions provided here](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2011/wsgi-under-cherrypy/) (it's definitely worth a read, though I'm not sure how up to date it is).

```
import cherrypy
from hello import app

cherrypy.tree.graft(app, '/')
cherrypy.tree.mount(None, '/static', {'/' : {
    'tools.staticdir.dir': app.static_folder,
    'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    }})
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_port': 8080,
    })
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Comment: I'll try it out tonight and if it works I'll set as answer. I've been googling for so long.  Thanks!