# Using Flask with CherryPy to serve static files

Tags: python, flask, cherrypy

First time using a web framework, hope to get advice on the correct approach.

My aim is to have a server which can return static files based on a url passed in. I use Flask as my web framework and I intent to use CherryPy as my web server. The web describes many ways of setting up Flask with CherryPy and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Resources I have been using:

- http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2011/wsgi-under-cherrypy/
- [Flask, CherryPy and static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315787/flask-cherrypy-and-static-content)
- http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2012/12/08/setting-up-a-rock-solid-python-development-web-server/
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/
- http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/

A simplified version of my Flask app, test.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import send_from_directory
import os

FOLDER='contents'
ROOT=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', FOLDER))

@app.route("/get")
def route_3():
    return flask.send_from_directory(os.path.join(ROOT, 'p01', 'p02'), 'file12.zip', as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config.update(DEBUG=True)
    app.run()
```

My script for to run CherryPy:

```
import os
import cherrypy
from test import app
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

def option_1():
    cherrypy.tree.graft(app, '/')

    # If I comment this out, the server works
    #cherrypy.tree.mount(None, '/', config={
    #        '/': {
    #                'tools.staticdir.on': True,
    #                'tools.staticdir.dir': app.static_folder
    #            },
    #    })

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 5000})

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()


def option2():
    d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app})
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 5000), d)
    try:
       server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       server.stop()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    #option_1()
    option_2()
```

I have two questions:

1. In terms of setting up CherryPy to run Flask, both option_1 and option_2 works, so what is the difference between the two?
2. It is recommended to have the web server serve the static files as opposed to the web framework. Am I doing this correctly? When I read the response header, the server is not ' Werkzeug', so I am assuming that the CherryPy server is sending it.

Comment: I use cherrypy as a replacement to the in-built dev server. In deployment I have nginx serve "/static" and then the rest is proxied back to gunicorn or uwsgi. I would not worry to much about this as you should _NEVER_ use the Werkzeug test server to deploy. If you prefer you could just replace the test server with CherryPy as a whole http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/

Comment: @JoeDoherty. Yes that is my goal, to replace the Werkzeug server with CherryPy. The problem is I am not sure if I have done it correctly. Thanks for the link; I did use it for option_2; just forgot to quote it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Option 1 is high-level CherryPy

`option_1` actually uses the entirety of the CherryPy web framework (which their documentation [refers to as the APPLICATION layer](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/cherrypy.html)) to mount your WSGI application - plugins, tools, etc. can be utilized fully.  To serve static files with CherryPy you would want to change your commented out code to be something like this:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(None, '/static', config={
    '/': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': app.static_folder
    },
})
```

#### Option 2 is low-level CherryPy

`option_2`, on the other hand, simply makes use of CherryPy's WSGI server implementation ([the CORE layer](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/refman/cherrypy.html)) to serve your Flask app - it does not use any of the more framework-like aspects of CherryPy.  If you are fine with serving your static files through Flask's routing layer as well, you can even remove the `WSGIPathInfoDispatcher` middleware and directly mount `app` under the `CherryPyWSGIServer`.  If you want CherryPy to manage the `/static` route serving then you will want to mount an instance of `cherrypy.tools.staticdir.handler` under the `/static` route, like so:

```
static_handler = tools.staticdir.handler(section='/', dir=app.static_folder)
d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app, '/static': static_handler})
```

Comment: Thanks @Sean that's useful! In that case, I think option_2 will suit my needs since I do not intent to use CherryPy's framework. An extra question: In what scenario would you choose option_1 though? If you are going to use another web framework to do the work, why would you still want to keep cherrypy's one?

Comment: @gilamesh - in a case where some portions of your application's functionality could be more easily created with CherryPy, you could avoid re-inventing the wheel for your framework of choice and just mount your CherryPy-based portion of the application alongside your other framework.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting option 2 to work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356166/keyerror-with-cherrypy-wsgiserver-serving-static-files

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the development server provided inside Werkzeug, I use the following in Flask-Script to replace `runserver()`. This will however in `__main__`

```
def runserver():
    """
    Overwriting the Flask Script runserver() default.
    CherryPy is much more stable than the built-in Flask dev server
    """
    debug_app = DebuggedApplication(app, True)
    cherrypy.tree.graft(debug_app, '/')
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'engine.autoreload_on': True,
        'server.socket_port': 5000,
        'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'
    })
    try:
        cherrypy.engine.start()
        cherrypy.engine.block()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cherrypy.engine.stop()
```

If you do not have DebuggedApplication wrapper the `DEBUG = True` will not work. You may need to adjust this slightly based on your application. It will also provide `Ctrl+C`

Joe

Comment: Thanks @Joe for the tip! I am afraid this is not what I am after; I use Werkeug as the development server and plan CherryPy as the acutal one. Reason being is my needs are modest and I am still new to setting up web server